# Pygame playing noise by frequency, hold, and playing simultaneous notes

Tags: python, audio, pygame

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import math

pygame.init()

# Set the sample rate and bit size for the audio
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=44100, size=-16, channels=10, buffer=2**12)

# Create a small window in the background (1x1 size)
pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1), pygame.NOFRAME)

# Define the piano sounds
frequencies = [
    {"Note": "C2", "Frequency": 65.41},
    {"Note": "C", "Frequency": 130.81},
    {"Note": "D", "Frequency": 146.83},
    {"Note": "E", "Frequency": 164.81},
    # Add more notes as needed
]

# Create a dictionary to map key codes to notes and channels
key_mapping = {
    pygame.K_a: {"Note": "C2", "Channel": None},
    pygame.K_s: {"Note": "C", "Channel": None},
    pygame.K_d: {"Note": "D", "Channel": None},
    pygame.K_f: {"Note": "E", "Channel": None},
    # Add more key mappings as needed
}

# Create sound objects for each note
sounds = {}
for note_info in frequencies:
    note = note_info["Note"]
    frequency = note_info["Frequency"]

    wave_array = np.array([int(32767.0 * math.sin(2.0 * math.pi * frequency * t / 44100.0)) for t in range(44100)], dtype=np.int16)
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(wave_array)
    sounds[note] = sound

# Main loop
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            key = event.key
            if key in key_mapping:
                note_info = key_mapping[key]
                note = note_info["Note"]
                if note_info["Channel"] is None:
                    prit(f"Played {note}")
                    channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
                    if channel:
                        channel.play(sounds[note], loops=-1)
                        note_info["Channel"] = channel
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            key = event.key
            if key in key_mapping:
                note_info = key_mapping[key]
                note = note_info["Note"]
                if note_info["Channel"]:
                    print(f"Stopped {note}")
                    note_info["Channel"].stop()
                    note_info["Channel"] = None

# Clean up
pygame.quit()
```

My code makes your keys A,S,D,F play different notes by frequency, but I can't get them to hold smoothly, does anyone know how I can fix this? Also when I press 2 keys at once, it makes a weird sound, is there a way to fix both of these? PS: You need to open the pygame window that pops up in order to work the keybinds

I tried playing the same note in different channels, delayed to smoothly loop, but it still doesn't work. I also tried to play the different notes in different channels so it doesn't make a weird sound when playing 2 notes simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

```
    wave_array = np.array(
        [
            int(32767.0 * math.sin(2.0 * math.pi * frequency * t / 44100.0))
            for t in range(44100)
        ],
        dtype=np.int16,
    )
```

> but I can't get them to hold smoothly

You are complaining about a 1 Hz clicking artifact in the audio.

You generate a nice smooth 1-second sample [sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation#Table_of_note_frequencies) wave of C below middle C, and then you abruptly switch to a different
sample of similar sine wave.
The waves do not match up.

You could address this by making the samples match.
Or more simply with a cross-fade, where for a brief interval
we mix together `t` × old sample
plus `(1 - t)` × new sample.

> when I press 2 keys at once, it makes a weird sound

We describe this as one frequency
"[beating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) against"
the other frequency, and it is fundamental.
The background story to Bach's
[Well Tempered Clavier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Well-Tempered_Clavier)
was all about coping with this effect
in an aesthetically pleasing way.
You are free to alter the
[frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency)
associated with each keypress,
in an effort to produce a well tempered computer keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct idea, but there are a few problems, some and some out of your control.

First, you will need to make sure you have a full period of the sine wave you are going to generate

```py
wave_length_in_samples = np.floor(float(sample_rate)/float(frequency))
```

create a `sample_rate` variable to make the job easy for you.

```
sample_rate = 48000
```

You can use this as the basis for generating the tone. I would eschew the `math` library and just stick to `numpy` if that is what you are already using.

```py
k = 1.0 / float(sample_rate)
y = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * float(frequency) * k * np.r_[0:wave_length_in_samples])
wave_array = np.array(gain * y, dtype=np.int16)
```

You might notice a `gain` variable added in there. Since you will be summing multiple tones together, you want to make sure you have enough headroom to avoid clipping. You can potentially play `4` tones, so it seems best to set the maximum to `0.25` or 1/4

```py
gain = 32767.0 * 0.25
```

Finally, you are unlikely to stop ate a sample value that is equal to `0`, in which case you will want to fade in and out.

In your case, to fade in is:

```py
channel.play(sounds[note], loops=-1, fade_ms=150)
```

and rather than simply using `stop` the sound, you can use `fadeout`

```
note_info["Channel"].fadeout(50)
```

Add that all together and you should end up with something like

```py
import pygame
import numpy as np

sample_rate = 48000
pygame.mixer.pre_init(sample_rate, -16, 1, 512)
pygame.init()

# Create a small window in the background (1x1 size)
pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1), pygame.NOFRAME)

# Define the piano sounds
frequencies = [
    {"Note": "C2", "Frequency": 65.41},
    {"Note": "C", "Frequency": 130.81},
    {"Note": "D", "Frequency": 146.83},
    {"Note": "E", "Frequency": 164.81},
    # Add more notes as needed
]

# Create a dictionary to map key codes to notes and channels
key_mapping = {
    pygame.K_a: {"Note": "C2", "Channel": None},
    pygame.K_s: {"Note": "C", "Channel": None},
    pygame.K_d: {"Note": "D", "Channel": None},
    pygame.K_f: {"Note": "E", "Channel": None},
    # Add more key mappings as needed
}

# Create sound objects for each note
sounds = {}
for note_info in frequencies:
    note = note_info["Note"]
    frequency = note_info["Frequency"]
    wave_length_in_samples = np.floor(float(sample_rate)/float(frequency))
    print("frequency", frequency,"wave_length_in_samples", wave_length_in_samples, "duration", 1/float(frequency))
    gain = 32767.0 * 0.25
    k = 1.0 / float(sample_rate)
    y = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * float(frequency) * k * np.r_[0:wave_length_in_samples])
    y = np.array(gain*y, dtype=np.int16)
    wave_array = np.vstack((y,y)).T.copy(order='C')
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(array=wave_array)
    sounds[note] = sound

# Main loop
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key in key_mapping:
            key = event.key
            note_info = key_mapping[key]
            note = note_info["Note"]
            if note_info["Channel"] is None:
                print(f"Played {note}")
                channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
                if channel:
                    channel.play(sounds[note], loops=-1, fade_ms=150)
                    note_info["Channel"] = channel
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            key = event.key
            if key in key_mapping:
                note_info = key_mapping[key]
                note = note_info["Note"]
                if note_info["Channel"]:
                    print(f"Stopped {note}")
                    note_info["Channel"].fadeout(50)
                    note_info["Channel"] = None

# Clean up
pygame.quit()
```

**NOTE:** I have found that the sampling rate seems to change the pitch on my own installation of pygame and that really shouldn't be the case. The change in phase is accommodated for in the tone generation. The number of channels is also addressed, so this seems to be a bug with pygame. There is also still some noise from the tone, which appears to be down to how ygame deals with the looping. Not a lot of noise, but still enough you can tell with a pure tone. Perhaps with a square or triangle wave you would be unlikely to tell.

The fading functions are also not great and produce a lot of noise. There is nothing you can do about that. This behaviour may have changed in a later version, so your mileage may vary.

In sum, you were very close and did a good job, but even then pygame still has some bugs.

Going forward my recommendation would be to generate the audio files first, perhaps as a `.wav`, save them and then load them in your script with `pygame.mixer.Sound`

**EDIT**
Best practice appears to be to call `pygame.mixer.pre_init` over `pygame.mixer.init`, you will need to do so *before* your call to `pygame.init`.

You will also need to provide an interleaved buffer of samples if there are multiple channels

e.g.

```
y = np.array([np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * float(frequency) * k * float(t//number_of_channels)) for t in range(int(wave_length_in_samples * number_of_channels))])
y = np.array(gain*y, dtype=np.int16)
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=samples)
```

Pygame seems a little more geared up for taking in array buffers than arrays

Finally, if the noise added by having an asymmetric wave period is too much you will need to adjust the frequency so that it's period can be expressed in a whole number of samples

```
wave_length_in_samples = np.floor(float(sample_rate)/float(frequency))
frequency = float(sample_rate) / wave_length_in_samples # redefine frequency
```

This will have tuning implications. Typically tone like this are stepped through using a Phasor. The noise problem is only as a result trying to loop over a buffer